# How to highlight bar in Bar Chart from custom method using ios charts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am using bar chart of ios charts and I am trying to highlight single bar without tap specific bar. If i change value from slider (if slider value move to 50) then a bar which contains the value (50) must be highlight without tap on bar using ios-charts

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430461/how-to-add-marker-to-center-position-in-ios-charts-while-scrolling-horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iOS-Charts` api is identical to the [`MPAndroidChart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) android library. So you can refer to `MPAndroidChart`'s docs. From [this page](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart), you can see that there are a couple methods available to make a selection programmatically :

> **Highlighting programmatically**
>
> `highlightValues(Highlight[] highs)`: Highlights the values at the given indices in the given DataSets. Provide null or an empty array to undo all highlighting.
>
> `highlightValue(int xIndex, int dataSetIndex)`: Highlights the value at the given x-index in the given DataSet. Provide -1 as the x-index or dataSetIndex to undo all highlighting.
>
> `getHighlighted()`: Returns an Highlight[] array that contains information about all highlighted entries, their x-index and dataset-index.

so on the *sliderValueChanged* event you could call something like this :

```
[_chartView highlightValueWithXIndex:2 dataSetIndex:0 callDelegate:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ShahiM.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

For single and multiple values:

```
chartHighlight = [[ChartHighlight alloc] initWithXIndex:highlightIndex.item dataSetIndex:0];

[_chartView highlightValues:@[chartHighlight]];
```